# asp.net nested gridview template controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested

I have a gridview inside a gridview's "ItemTemplate".  The outside gridview, (gvPOs) , has a "select" option.  Since my sql data source is handled through code behind, not sqldatasource through design mode, there's no "enable select" , "enable delete", etc.  So I added select under "edit columns" as a CommandField.  Usually, when a gridview is by itself , and I make a formview using the table data to display that information, I can just fill in the where clause to display where ID is from gvPOs.SelectedValue control and it would show that specific line.  But in this case, since there's a nested gridview, for some reason when I do that, "select" doesn't do anything.

[image: Output]

I'm trying to get the select on the far right column of the outside gridview to open up my formview that corresponds to the PO_ID.

The left side is just to show what else it's doing.  When the expand button is clicked on the left, the 2nd gridview pops up with the records that have that PO_ID.  My overall goal is to be able to add, delete, and edit records from both tables.

Code Behind:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
   namespace PO_1_5_15
{
    public partial class _Webform : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                gvPOs.DataSource = GetData("select * from dbo.po_table");
                gvPOs.DataBind();

                FormView1.Visible = false;

            }

        }

        protected void gvTasks_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            gvPOs.DataBind();
        }



        private static DataTable GetData(string query)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test_DatabaseConnectionString3"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Show_Hide_ChildGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imgShowHide = (sender as ImageButton);
    GridViewRow row = (imgShowHide.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);

    if (imgShowHide.CommandArgument == "Show")
    {
        row.FindControl("pnlTasks").Visible = true;
        imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Hide";
        imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "~/images/minus.png";
        string POId = gvPOs.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        GridView gvTasks = row.FindControl("gvTasks") as GridView; gvTasks.ToolTip = POId;

        gvTasks.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select * from task where po_Id='{0}'", POId));
        gvTasks.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        row.FindControl("pnlTasks").Visible = false;
        imgShowHide.CommandArgument = "Show";
        imgShowHide.ImageUrl = "~/images/plus.png";
    }
}



private void BindTasks(string POId, GridView gvTasks)
{
    gvTasks.ToolTip = POId;
    gvTasks.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select * from task where po_Id='{0}'", POId));
    gvTasks.DataBind();
}
protected void OnChildGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gvTasks = (sender as GridView);
    gvTasks.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindTasks(gvTasks.ToolTip, gvTasks);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormView1.Visible = true;
 //   FormView2.Visible = false;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //   FormView2.Visible = true;
    FormView1.Visible = false;
}

protected void FormView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvPOs.DataBind();
}



protected void gvTasks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvPOs.DataBind();
}
    }
}
```

HTML Markup:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Webform.aspx.cs" Inherits="PO_1_5_15._Webform" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ChildGrid {
            margin-right: 2px;
        }
        .Grid {
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add PO" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Add Task" />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvPOs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="PO_ID" EnableModelValidation="True" >

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgShow" runat="server" OnClick="Show_Hide_ChildGrid" ImageUrl="~/images/plus.png"
                    CommandArgument="Show" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlTasks" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="position: relative">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvTasks" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" 
                        AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnChildGrid_PageIndexChanging" CssClass="ChildGrid" EnableModelValidation="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="PO_ID" HeaderText="PO #" >
                             <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Invoice_No" HeaderText="Invoice #" >
                             <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Invoice_Date" HeaderText="Invoice Date" >
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Task_Note" HeaderText="Task Note" >
                             <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" >
                             <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="UserDate" HeaderText="Current Date/Time" >
                             <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="_Status" HeaderText="Status" >
                             <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Cost" >
                              <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                              <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Services" HeaderText="Service" >
                            <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="PO_ID" HeaderText="PO #" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Invoice_No" HeaderText="Invoice #" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="UserDate" HeaderText="Current Date/Time" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="PO_Note" HeaderText="PO Note" >
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

            <br />
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PO_AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True" OnPageIndexChanging="FormView1_PageIndexChanging">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    PO_AutoID:
                    <asp:Label ID="PO_AutoIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PO_AutoID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_ID:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_Title:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PO_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Date_Received:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Date_ReceivedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Date_Completed:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Date_CompletedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Username:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserDate:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserDate") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_Note:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PO_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Department:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DepartmentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Invoice_No:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Invoice_NoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_No") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    PO_ID:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PO_IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_Title:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PO_TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Date_Received:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Date_ReceivedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Date_Completed:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Date_CompletedTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Username:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserDate:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserDate") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_Note:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="PO_NoteTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Department:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="DepartmentTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Invoice_No:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Invoice_NoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_No") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    PO_AutoID:
                    <asp:Label ID="PO_AutoIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PO_AutoID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_ID:
                    <asp:Label ID="PO_IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_ID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_Title:
                    <asp:Label ID="PO_TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Title") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Date_Received:
                    <asp:Label ID="Date_ReceivedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Received") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Date_Completed:
                    <asp:Label ID="Date_CompletedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date_Completed") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Username:
                    <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' />
                    <br />
                    UserDate:
                    <asp:Label ID="UserDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserDate") %>' />
                    <br />
                    PO_Note:
                    <asp:Label ID="PO_NoteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PO_Note") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Department:
                    <asp:Label ID="DepartmentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Department") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Invoice_No:
                    <asp:Label ID="Invoice_NoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Invoice_No") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="New" Text="New" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString3 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PO_Table] WHERE ([PO_ID] = @PO_ID)" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [PO_Table] WHERE [PO_AutoID] = @PO_AutoID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [PO_Table] ([PO_ID], [PO_Title], [Date_Received], [Date_Completed], [Username], [UserDate], [PO_Note], [Department], [Invoice_No]) VALUES (@PO_ID, @PO_Title, @Date_Received, @Date_Completed, @Username, @UserDate, @PO_Note, @Department, @Invoice_No)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PO_Table] SET [PO_ID] = @PO_ID, [PO_Title] = @PO_Title, [Date_Received] = @Date_Received, [Date_Completed] = @Date_Completed, [Username] = @Username, [UserDate] = @UserDate, [PO_Note] = @PO_Note, [Department] = @Department, [Invoice_No] = @Invoice_No WHERE [PO_AutoID] = @PO_AutoID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Received" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Completed" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Note" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_No" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvPOs" Name="PO_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Received" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Date_Completed" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_Note" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_No" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Test_DatabaseConnectionString3 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Task] WHERE [Task_AutoID] = @Task_AutoID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Task] ([PO_AutoID], [PO_ID], [Task_Title], [Username], [UserDate], [Cost], [_Status], [Invoice_Date], [Paid_Date], [Task_Note], [Department], [Invoice_No], [Services]) VALUES (@PO_AutoID, @PO_ID, @Task_Title, @Username, @UserDate, @Cost, @column1, @Invoice_Date, @Paid_Date, @Task_Note, @Department, @Invoice_No, @Services)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Task]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Task] SET [PO_AutoID] = @PO_AutoID, [PO_ID] = @PO_ID, [Task_Title] = @Task_Title, [Username] = @Username, [UserDate] = @UserDate, [Cost] = @Cost, [_Status] = @column1, [Invoice_Date] = @Invoice_Date, [Paid_Date] = @Paid_Date, [Task_Note] = @Task_Note, [Department] = @Department, [Invoice_No] = @Invoice_No, [Services] = @Services WHERE [Task_AutoID] = @Task_AutoID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Task_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Paid_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Note" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_No" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Services" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PO_ID" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserDate" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Cost" Type="Decimal" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="column1" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Paid_Date" Type="DateTime" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Task_Note" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Invoice_No" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Services" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Task_AutoID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <br />
            <br />

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand your problem 100%. if you want to use nested GridView, bind child GridView in Row_DataBound event of parent GridView. Make sure you bind parent gridview inside if(!Page.IsPostBack) condition so once you hit select button it won't bind parent GridView.

Sample code for ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SO_GVSample.aspx.cs" Inherits="MVCWeb.SO_GVSample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:GridView ID="gvParent" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvParent_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Parent ID" DataField="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="cmdSelect" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlChild" runat="server">
            Child Record
            <hr />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvChild" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvChild_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Parent ID" DataField="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" CommandName="cmdCSelect" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlForm" runat="server">
            Form View
            <hr />
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Form ID:</b></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("ChildID") %></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Child ID:</b></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Form Desc:</b></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("Description") %> </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
        </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MVCWeb
{
    public partial class SO_GVSample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                gvParent.DataSource = GetParentData();
                gvParent.DataBind();

                pnlForm.Visible = false;
            }

        }

        #region Events

        protected void gvParent_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "cmdSelect")
            {
                gvChild.DataSource = GetChildData().Where(c => c.ParentID == Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                gvChild.DataBind();

                pnlForm.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        protected void gvChild_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "cmdCSelect")
            {
                FormView1.DataSource = GetFormData().Where(c => c.ChildID == Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                FormView1.DataBind();

                pnlForm.Visible = true;
            }
        }


        #endregion


        #region Data Source

        private List<ParentClass> GetParentData()
        {
            return new List<ParentClass>()
            {
                new ParentClass{ ID=1, Description="Parent Record 1"},
                new ParentClass{ ID=2, Description="Parent Record 2"},
                new ParentClass{ ID=3, Description="Parent Record 3"},
                new ParentClass{ ID=4, Description="Parent Record 4"},
                new ParentClass{ ID=5, Description="Parent Record 5"}
            };
        }

        private List<ChildClass> GetChildData()
        {
            return new List<ChildClass>()
            {
                new ChildClass{ ID=11, ParentID=1,  Description="Child Record 11"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=12, ParentID=1,  Description="Child Record 12"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=22,ParentID=2, Description="Child Record 22"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=23,ParentID=2, Description="Child Record 23"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=33,ParentID=3, Description="Child Record 3"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=44,ParentID=4, Description="Child Record 4"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=55, ParentID=5,Description="Child Record 55"},
                new ChildClass{ ID=56, ParentID=5,Description="Child Record 56"}
            };
        }

        private List<FormViewClass> GetFormData()
        {
            return new List<FormViewClass>()
            {
                new FormViewClass{ ID=111, ChildID=11,  Description="FormView Record 11"},
                new FormViewClass{ ID=222,ChildID=22, Description="FormView Record 22"},
                new FormViewClass{ ID=333,ChildID=33, Description="FormView Record 3"},
                new FormViewClass{ ID=444,ChildID=44, Description="FormView Record 4"},
                new FormViewClass{ ID=555, ChildID=55,Description="FormView Record 55"},
                 new FormViewClass{ ID=111, ChildID=12,  Description="FormView Record 11"},
                new FormViewClass{ ID=222,ChildID=23, Description="FormView Record 22"},            
                new FormViewClass{ ID=555, ChildID=56,Description="FormView Record 55"},
            };
        }

        public class ParentClass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        public class ChildClass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public int ParentID { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        public class FormViewClass
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

            public int ChildID { get; set; }

            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

        #endregion


    }
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I added some code and edited it above.  I want to be able to use options like "Select" from a gridview.  When I click "Select", a Formview should open with the PO_ID info that I selected. And on that formview, I can edit, insert, or delete a record.  It's easier when they're not nested.  But anyway, I may or may not have binded the right gridviews correctly in my code.  When I change it to the other gridview, I get an error.  gvPOs is the parent gridview and gvTasks is the child.

Comment: (I'm just copying my reply to direct to you) I added some code and edited it above. I want to be able to use options like "Select" from a gridview. When I click "Select", a Formview should open with the PO_ID info that I selected. And on that formview, I can edit, insert, or delete a record. It's easier when they're not nested. But anyway, I may or may not have binded the right gridviews correctly in my code. When I change it to the other gridview, I get an error. gvPOs is the parent gridview and gvTasks is the child.

Comment: Do you want like below.

Bind Parent Grid --> Select parent grid Item --> Populate Child Grid based on parent Grid selected item (Only one child Grid (for Selected parent item) will be visible at a time)  --> Select Child Grid Item --> Populate FormView based on selected child item (Only one FoemView (for Selected child item) will be visible at a time).

If it is different then above, please let me know flow like above and I'll prepare sample and will post it here.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll test it out using my tables/data.

Comment: In the code I have posted has some temp data in it so you can just copy/paste and runt it, if it match with your requirement then update your datasource.